# Bulkifying Location-Based SOQL Query

Tags: apex

I have a use case where I need to identify Sites (a custom record) that are nearby an Account's mailing address. Ideally, I'd like to run this logic whenever an Account is created or when the mailing address is updated. The code/query when thinking about this logic for a single Account record would look something like this:

```
Decimal latString = [Select MailingLatitude From Account WHERE ID=:IDPassedIntoApex].MailingLatitude; 
Decimal longString = [Select MailingLongitude From Contact WHERE ID =:IDPassedIntoApex].MailingLongitude;
<Site__c> siteList = [SELECT ID FROM Site__c WHERE DISTANCE(Site_Geo_Address_c, GEOLOCATION(:latString, :longString), 'mi')
```

However, my question is how would I go about bulkifying this location-based SOQL query, since the query is specific to the MailingLatitude and MailingLongitude fields on each individual Account record?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on **[`Location-Based SOQL Queries`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm)** seems to clearly indicate only a single value can be passed into the `DISTANCE` function.

> ### WHERE Clause
>
> Retrieve records with locations within or outside of a certain radius with distance conditions in the WHERE clause of the query. To construct an appropriate distance condition, use the following functions.
>
> #### DISTANCE
>
> Calculates the distance between two locations in miles or kilometers.
> Usage: `DISTANCE(mylocation1, mylocation2, 'unit')` and replace `mylocation1` and `mylocation2` with two location fields, or a location field and a value returned by the `GEOLOCATION` function. Replace unit with mi (miles) or km (kilometers).

Notice the use of singular in reference to the `GEOLOCATION` function. You will either need to query separately for each `DISTANCE`, or use a giant `OR` clause (if it even works).